# Delete Instance of Object in React: 'car' is returning undefined

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to update my app so that each car displayed comes with a delete button, which would remove the car from the database upon click.

In my deleteButton component, I have the following which gives me the error message `car is not defined`:

```
import React from 'react';

class DeleteButton extends React.Component {
constructor() {
    super();
        this.state = {
        };
        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
}

delete(car){
    const data = this.state.data.filter(i => i.id !== car.id)
    this.setState({data})
  }

render() {
    const label = 'Delete';
        return (
            <button className="delete-btn" onClick={this.delete.bind(this, car)}>{label}</button>
        );
    }
}

export default DeleteButton;
```

How should I be defining `car`?

Comment: Where is `car`comming from? Where `this.state.data` comming from? What is inside `this.state.data`?

Comment: do you use redux? could be the right time to implement it since you require data access from a sub component. Or you should be creating the delete function in the parent where it can access the full list of data.

Comment: I'm using Redux as well, maybe that's the better approach?

Answer (score 0):

**1.** You need to put car in state like this:

```
    this.state = {
      car: {
        id: ''
      },
    };
```

But problem is data, you need tu provide data as props to the Delete Component.

And then from props take data not from state.

**2.** Then onDelete function update state:

```
delete(car){
    const data = this.props.data.filter(i => i.id !== car.id)
    this.setState({car: data})
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, I added it, but am getting `can't read property 'bind' of undefined`

Comment: Cus you don't have defined handleClick() function. Can you paste code of parent compnent place where you call Delete component? 
And Enitre code of parent component.